# When using std::set_intersection, which set is used to copy the values into the destination set?

Tags: c++, stl

I was using set_intersection from the STL in C++, and I was wondering if there was any rule on which set would be used when creating the intersection.  Or is the behavior undefined, and potentially implementation dependent.

On linux using g++ (ver. 4.4.6), it seems that it always uses the first set that is passed into the set_difference function, but I'm not sure I can rely on this.  As you can see from the example below, there is other data in each set member that is not considered in the operator< function.

```
#include <set>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class myClass {
  public:
    myClass(int val, int data)
        : value(val),
          metaData(data) {}

    // Only consider the value, not metaData
    bool operator<(const myClass &other) const{
        return value < other.value;
    }

    void print() const {
        cout << "Value: " << value << " metaData: " << metaData << endl;
    }

  private:
    int value;
    int metaData;

};

int main() {
    // Create two sets with some data
    set<myClass> set1;
    set<myClass> set2;
    set<myClass> intersect;

    // Set1 has 1, 2, 3, 4
    set1.insert(myClass(1,-10));
    set1.insert(myClass(2,-10));
    set1.insert(myClass(3,-10));
    set1.insert(myClass(4,-10));

    // Set2 has -1, 2, 3
    set2.insert(myClass(-1, 10));
    set2.insert(myClass(2, 10));
    set2.insert(myClass(3, 10));

    set_intersection(set1.begin(), set1.end(),
                   set2.begin(), set2.end(),
                   inserter(intersect, intersect.begin()));

    for_each(intersect.begin(), intersect.end(),
             mem_fun_ref(&myClass::print));

}
// The output of this code is 
// Value: 2 metaData: -10
// Value: 3 metaData: -10
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking here when you say "which set would be used when creating the intersection".

Comment: Also, your question title mentions `set_intersection`, but your code uses `set_difference`...

Comment: Oops, I meant set_intersection in the code.  I tested it again just to be sure, and it does take from the first set.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you're asking about `set_intersection` as in the question title, rather than `set_difference` as in the code sample, the C++ standard is explicit:

`C++03 §25.3.5.3[lib.set.intersection]/5`

> if an element is present in both ranges, the one from the first range is copied

Current standard makes this point even stronger, mostly for the sake of multisets which are now stable with regards to the order of equivalent keys:

`C++11 §25.4.5.3[set.intersection]/5`

> If `[first1,last1)` contains `m` elements that are equivalent to each other and `[first2,
>   last2)` contains `n` elements that are equivalent to them, the first `min(m, n)` elements shall be copied from the first range to the output range, in order.

As for `set_difference`, it simply copies the elements of the first sorted sequence that are not present in the second.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for! I fixed the code and comment, I meant to use set_intersection, not set_difference.

Answer (score 1):

From [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/set_difference/),

> The difference of two sets is formed by the elements that are present
>   in the first set, but not in the second one.

I know of no instance where this site has provided incorrect information.

Comment: Thanks, I accidentally used set_difference in the code, I meant to use set_intersection.